# How to Display Case Number on automatic email response with Email-to-Case

Tags: trigger, email-template, singleemailmessage, email2case, merge-field

I am trying to include Case Number of an email template for an email-to-case.
Basically, when a client sent an email to a closed case, he received an automatic email reply. I would like the automatic email reply to show the case number.
On the template I have added the merge field value {!Case.CaseNumber}

[image]

but the Case Number does not appear on the email reply sent to the client

[image]

I believe that, to add the Case Number in the automatic email reply, I need to reference the CaseId somewhere in my code. But I haven't figured out how.
I tried to do :

> mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Id);

I Hoped to get the case number but this does not work
Here is my full code:
Apex Class:

```
public class EmailManager {
@future
public static void sendEmailToCaseDeactivated(Set<Id> caseIds){

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<Case> lstCase = [SELECT Id, Status,ContactEmail FROM Case WHERE 
                          Status = 'Closed' AND
                          ContactEmail != Null AND
                          Id IN: caseIds];
    EmailTemplate templateId = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =:'Email_to_Case_Closed'];
   
    for(Case c : lstCase) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
        mail.setTemplateId(templateId.Id);
        String[] sendingTo = new String[]{c.ContactEmail}; 
        mail.setToAddresses(sendingTo); 
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        allmsg.add(mail);
    }               
    Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg, false);
}

}
```

Apex Trigger:

```
trigger IncomingEmailClosedCase on EmailMessage (before insert,after insert) {

if(trigger.isBefore) { 
    Set<Id> sCaseIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(EmailMessage em: Trigger.New) {
        if (em.Incoming)
             sCaseIds.add(em.parentId);   
    }
    if(!sCaseIds.isEmpty())
        EmailManager.sendEmailToCaseDeactivated(sCaseIds);
}
if(trigger.isAfter){
    Map<Id,Id> caseIdsToEmailMessageIds = new Map<Id,Id>();
    for(EmailMessage em: Trigger.New) {
        if (em.Incoming)
            caseIdsToEmailMessageIds.put(em.parentId,em.Id);   
    }
    set<Id> sMessageIdsToDelete = new Set<Id>();
    if(caseIdsToEmailMessageIds.isEmpty()) return;
    for(Case lstCase : [SELECT Id, Status,ContactEmail FROM Case WHERE 
                      Status = 'Closed' AND
                      ContactEmail != Null AND
                      Id IN: caseIdsToEmailMessageIds.keyset()]){
        if(caseIdsToEmailMessageIds.containsKey(lstCase.Id)){
            Id emId = caseIdsToEmailMessageIds.get(lstCase.Id);
            sMessageIdsToDelete.add(emId);
        } 
    } 
    if(!sMessageIdsToDelete.isEmpty())   delete [ select Id from EmailMessage where id in :sMessageIdsToDelete];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The merge fields in an email template that reference the `relatedTo` object (in VF email template terms) must set the `whatId`

> setWhatId(whatId)

> If you specify a contact for the targetObjectId
> field, you can specify an optional whatId as well. This helps to
> further ensure that merge fields in the template contain the correct
> data.

and, per the doc, you should `setTargetObjectId(c.ContactId)` instead of to the running user.